# Is there a way to define a separate listings escape sequence?

Tags: listings, delimiters

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside={`}{`},
  escapebegin={\color{darkgray}\textlangle},
  escapeend={\textrangle}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
`what`
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The escape sequence *`* is supposed to have the specific use case of styling place-holder values in code (eg. ).

I'd like to be able to have a separate escape sequence for more general things. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible: only one pair of escape sequences are allowed per listing.

You can instead define macros for the various tasks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  frame=tb,
  columns=fullflexible,
  escapeinside={`}{`},
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\AAA}{m}{\textcolor{darkgray}{\textlangle #1\textrangle}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\BBB}{m}{\textcolor{red!80}{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
xyz `\AAA{what}` uvw
abc `\BBB{where}` def
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If using LuaLatex, could a script be written to look for those delimiters in listings and substitute in the text macro?

Comment: @user41177 Possibly. I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: That's a shame. I will go with your answer. Thanks.